# Java - Pausing thread for input

Tags: java, concurrency, wait

I am having a problem with running Threads. See, I want to have a class purely for printing a passage of text slowly, ie waiting x milliseconds between each letter (think of it as the way text displays in Pokémon!). So at the moment, I have a Main class, and a "Print" class, which is static. In the Print class is a static method called slow. You pass in a String and a delay between each letter. The problem is, if in my Main class I say

```
Print.slow("Hello there, enter your name");
System.out.println("NAME:");
name = (scanner object).nextLine();
```

What happens is, while "Hello there, enter your name" is being read, you can enter input! I still need the Print.slow() method to sleep, so how can I make the main method pause until the passage has been read?

printSlow Method (the Print class was refractored into a method in main)

```
public static void printSlow(String passage, int delay)
{
    int normDelay = delay;
    char lastChar = 'a';
    for(int i=0; i<passage.length(); i++)
    {
        try {
            if(passage.charAt(i) == '.' && passage.charAt(i + 1) == '.') {
                System.out.print(".");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(normDelay*10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                continue;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print(".");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(normDelay*10);
            }catch(InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            continue;
        }
        if(passage.charAt(i) == ' ' && (lastChar == ',' || lastChar == '.' || lastChar == '!' || lastChar == '?'))
        {
            continue;
        }else
        {
            System.out.print(passage.charAt(i));
        }

        if(passage.substring(i, i + 1).equals(".")
        || passage.substring(i, i + 1).equals(",")
        || passage.substring(i, i + 1).equals("!")
        || passage.substring(i, i + 1).equals("?"))
        {
            System.out.println();
            delay = normDelay * 10;
        }
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(delay);
            delay = normDelay;
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        lastChar = passage.charAt(i);
    }
}
```

The reason it's so complicated is because I needed a longer delay after every full stop, comma etc, and also having three full stops in a row would not end up skipping 3 lines.

Comment: Threads are usually paused with Thread.sleep(), but I don't know if that will accomplish what you want here or not. Could you show the code of the Print.slow() method?

Answer (score 3):

If you want it to run synchronously, run it on the main thread; do not start another thread.

If you have to start another thread, use `Thread#join()` in the main thread just after invoking `Print.slow()`.  The `Print` class will need to provide a `getThread()` method so the main thread can get access to the print thread.

EDIT

I think we have a terminology problem

> ...while "Hello there, enter your name" is being read, you can enter input!

I now interpret this to mean that:

1. The string *Hello there...* is being displayed slowly
2. During this display the user is able to type characters which get interleaved with the output.

If that is what you mean, then your whole approach is incorrect.  You are using input and output streams which are being managed ultimately by the shell and connected to your process.  The OS/shell is buffering input and you are not in control.

If what you *really* want is to prevent any keystrokes from being recognized while output is occurring, this is a much more difficult problem, and will need to be OS-specific (i.e. non-portable).  You need to read directly from the input device and handle each keystroke yourself, which will be almost impossible using input/output streams.

You *could* get this level of control of you wrote a Swing app for the UI, which would allow you to intercept every event and do whatever you wanted.  As a plain command-line program it is unlikely you can achieve what you want.

Comment: I removed the Print class and refractored the slow method to printSlow in the Main class. I am still getting the same problem though.

Comment: Without seeing more code nobody can help you.  For reliable interactive input/output you must use unbuffered streams.

Comment: Jim Garrison's answer should solve your problem. If the only objective you are trying to achieve is to ask the main thread to wait until the Print thread has finished printing the passage, then it doesn't get any easier than calling join on the reference to the Print thread right after you call the Print.slow method. This will make the current thread, which is the main thread in your case, wait for the Print thread to complete its execution before it can execute any instructions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; I just tried calling Print.join() after calling Print.slow(), and the problem still persists.

Comment: Thanks for the update, Jim. Ah, that's quite disappointing; this problem is far more complicated than I had hoped...well anyway, this method is going to be used for a "beta" version of a Text-Based adventure I'm making with a friend, and we're planning on the next (FULL) version to be a GUI (With ascii maps in one box, input in another etc.), so it's not to big of a problem.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know what is going on without knowing more about your threads and seeing the `slow(...)` method.

> What happens is, while "Hello there, enter your name" is being read, you can enter input!

However, this may be a problem with the way input is read from the console.  Often console input is buffered so although you have not gotten to the `nextLine()` method in your main thread, the input is being recorded by the `InputStream` in question -- buffered by the system.  This may be the situation that you are seeing.

If you are seeing the `NAME:` prompt then something else is going on.